# ACORD standard to define a custom node?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have been working with ACORD XML standard for a while now with some success.
We now have a requirement to gather a piece of data which is custom to my company.  (ACORD doesn’t have a place for it.)

For example, if I currently have the following XML:

```
<InsuranceSvcRq>
<RqUID> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
<CommlPkgPolicyAddRq>
  <RqUID> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
  <ItemIdInfo>
    <SystemId> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SystemId>
  </ItemIdInfo>
  <TransactionRequestDt>2013-05-13T00:00:00-04:00</TransactionRequestDt>
  <CurCd>USD</CurCd>
  <BroadLOBCd>C</BroadLOBCd>
  <InsuredOrPrincipal>
    <ItemIdInfo>
      <SystemId> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SystemId>
    </ItemIdInfo>
    <GeneralPartyInfo>
      <NameInfo>
        <CommlName />
        <TaxIdentity>
          <StateProvCd>OH</StateProvCd>
        </TaxIdentity>
      </NameInfo>
    </GeneralPartyInfo>
    <InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
      <InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>Insured</InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>
    </InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
  </InsuredOrPrincipal>
  <CommlPolicy>
    <PolicyNumber>1111</PolicyNumber>
    <LOBCd>2222</LOBCd>
    <NAICCd>3333</NAICCd>
```

I need to add a new node under the CommPolicy node called Foo. See below.

```
<InsuranceSvcRq>
<RqUID> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
<CommlPkgPolicyAddRq>
  <RqUID> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
  <ItemIdInfo>
    <SystemId> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SystemId>
  </ItemIdInfo>
  <TransactionRequestDt>2013-05-13T00:00:00-04:00</TransactionRequestDt>
  <CurCd>USD</CurCd>
  <BroadLOBCd>C</BroadLOBCd>
  <InsuredOrPrincipal>
    <ItemIdInfo>
      <SystemId> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SystemId>
    </ItemIdInfo>
    <GeneralPartyInfo>
      <NameInfo>
        <CommlName />
        <TaxIdentity>
          <StateProvCd>OH</StateProvCd>
        </TaxIdentity>
      </NameInfo>
    </GeneralPartyInfo>
    <InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
      <InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>Insured</InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>
    </InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
  </InsuredOrPrincipal>
  <CommlPolicy>
    <PolicyNumber>1111</PolicyNumber>
    <Foo>4444</Foo>
    <LOBCd>2222</LOBCd>
    <NAICCd>3333</NAICCd>
```

Is there a standard to do that processing?  A naming convention to indicate that it is custom?  Are there any online articles regarding this topic?  (I couldn’t find any.)

Any information would be helpfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to assume that your question applies to ACORD's P&C Insurance and Surety. To understand the extension mechanism, the full spec as published with the package (the document I was using recently is *ACORD XML Business Message Specification for P&C Insurance and Surety Version 1.24.0*) contains what you need (section 14). [This document](http://www.acord.org/webfiles/education_support_files/pcs_xml_v1/pcsv1_all_modules.pdf) is training material that has a good section on extensions, which includes highlights on the naming conventions, processing models, etc. If you're looking for articles similar to how one might find about more generic things such as XML Schema spec, then there aren't that many. ACORD's website is the best source.

For the practical bit, [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) provides all the tools that one would need to practically manage extensions, generate XSDs and run compliance reports on the work that's done as per the spec.

Comment: Petru, Thanks for the response.  This should be enough to get me started.